# MySQL + JAVA Exception: Before start of result set

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
try
  {
   PreparedStatement  s = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("SELECT voters.Check,count(*) FROM voting.voters where FirstName="+first+"and LastName="+last+" and SSN="+voter_ID);
   //java.sql.Statement k = conn.createStatement();

         rs=s.executeQuery();
               //s.executeQuery("SELECT voters.Check,count(*) FROM voting.voters where FirstName="+first+"and LastName="+last+" and SSN="+voter_ID);

         System.out.println(rs.first());
         c=rs.getInt(1);
         d=rs.getInt(2);

         System.out.println(c);
         System.out.println(d);

          if(c==1 && d==1)
          {
           s.executeUpdate("update cand set total=total+1 where ssn="+can_ID);
           System.out.println("Succeful vote");
           System.out.println("after vote");
           s.executeUpdate("update voters set voters.Check=1 where ssn="+voter_ID);
                 toclient=1;



             PreparedStatement  qw = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("select FirstName from cand where ssn="+can_ID);

                 // rs=k.executeQuery("select FirstName from cand where ssn="+can_ID);
             rs1 = qw.executeQuery();//Error Here Plz help me
                  String name1= (String) rs1.getString(1);

                  System.out.println(name1);
                  s.executeUpdate("update voters set VTO="+name1+"where ssn="+voter_ID);
           System.out.println(rs.getString(1));

          }
          else
          {
           if(c != -1)
            toclient =2;
           if( d ==0)
            toclient =3;
           if( d>1)
            toclient =4;

          }
           System.out.println("out-----------");
           rs.close();

           s.close();

  }

   catch (SQLException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Error IS :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1072)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:986)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:981)
```

Comment: IMHO posting blocks of code and some exceptions without any attempt at an explanation isn't great :/

Comment: I prefer this to "I have a problem, please help" and no code whatsoever ;). And this one is quite easy, so not that bothered.

Comment: I see what you mean, I can't see the harm of *a little* explanation though. I guess there is a compromise.

Comment: Not taking benefit of preparedstatement powers (hardcoding values in query), not taking benefit of SQL powers (all unnecessary `SELECT` queries), poor SQL (that `count(*)` makes no sense), resource leaking (no closing in `finally`), poor code style (it isn't entirely clear what you're trying to achieve), poor datamodel (unclear columnnames and apparently no FK relations (using FirstName instead of ID)). I would like to help you out of this all, but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code snippet you create PreparedStatements but you do not use them correctly. Prepared statements are meant to be used as a kind of 'statement template' which is bound to values before it executes. To quote the javadoc:

```
   PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
                                 "UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET SALARY = ? WHERE ID = ?");
   pstmt.setBigDecimal(1, 153833.00)
   pstmt.setInt(2, 110592)
```

This has two big advantages over your current usage of PreparedStatement:

- one PreparedStatement can be used for multiple executes
- it **prevents** a possible **SQL injection** attack

The second one here is the biggie, if for instance your variables `first` and `last` are collected in a user interface and not reformatted, you run the risk of parts of SQL being input for those values, which then end up in your statements! Using bound parameters they will just be used as values, not part of the SQL statement.

Answer (score 2):

While `rs1.first()` may work, to avoid exception I would like to avoid it and use `rs1.next()` instead.

See javadoc of `ResultSet.first()`:

> SQLException - if a database access error occurs; this method is called on a closed result set or **the result set type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY**
>
> SQLFeatureNotSupportedException - **if the JDBC driver does not support this method**

while `next` doesn't have this limitation

Code:

```
if (rs1.next()) {
    String name1 = rs1.getString(1);
}
```

Tips: avoid useless type casting (your code is full of them)

Comment: his isn't a `FORWARD_ONLY`, I think

Comment: yup... but best practices are always good to be used

Comment: It's a best practice to call the method you actually need ;)

Comment: and to lose JDBC strength (DBMSs inter-compability) ?

Comment: in this case you are losing nothing. The method wouldn't be there if it didn't have usage.

Comment: first() is intended to be used when you go back-and-forth in the ResultSet. If that's your intention, you'll break the inter-compability for performance, and you clearly aware of this problem. For this very simple problem, not using the best practice means you teach the reader of the code a practice that would cause them problem in the future. So I keep my mind, use `next()` for inter-compability and avoid to use `first()` except you know that it improves performance significantly (after profiling of course).

Answer (score 2):

The common practice is to use `rs.next()` method with `while` cycle:

```
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("select 1 from mytable");
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
  // do something with result set
}
rs.close();
st.close();
```

I've omitted try/catch/finally clauses for clarity. Note that you should invoke each `close()` method in separate `finally` block.

Comment: he expects only 1 row (the query includes an `id`), so - `first()` is better.

Comment: Nope. Look at `rs1 = qw.executeQuery();//Error Here Plz help me` line and the declaration of `qw` above — I think the author _should_ expect more than one record in result set (but I may be wrong, of course — it is not so obvious without some explanations).

Comment: he's making the query by the (apparent) ID, which is unique.

Comment: Personally, I'm always doing either `while (rs.next())` for multiple results or `if (rs.next())` for single result.

Answer (score 1):

Call `rs1.first()` before using the `ResultSet`.

> Moves the cursor to the first row in this ResultSet object.

Initially the cursor position of the `ResultSet` is before the start of the set. The `first()` method returns `true` if there is data in the set. So preferably:

```
if (rs1.first()) {
    String name1 = (String) rs1.getString(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you get a resultset, the cursor is placed before the first row. Trying to get anything before moving your cursor to the first row will cause the error you received. You need to move the cursor to the first row using this line:

```
rs1.first();
```

before calling

```
String name1 = (String) rs1.getString(1);
```

Of course, make sure the resultset contains entries before calling rs1.getString(1).

Answer (score 0):

So, to be sure the proper use of PreparedStatment, here is your original example adjusted for best practices (note the cast is redundant):

```
PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT voters.Check,count(*) " +
    "FROM voting.voters " +
    "where FirstName=? and LastName=? and SSN=?");
s.setString(1,first);
s.setString(2,last);
s.setString(3,voter_ID);
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery();
while( rs.next() ) {
    c = rs.getInt(1);
    d = rs.getInt(2);
}
```

Hope this helps... :)