# Do not recreate database using robolectric

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, robolectric, android-testing

I know `Robolectric` is not using the real SQLite database, that it uses in memory database. But the database is recreated every time `getWritableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()` is called.

Is there a way to make `Robolectric` recreate the database let's say only when `setUp()` is called or something like that?

Comment: I think your database is in asset folder and when ever you are calling getWritableDatabase(), every time its getting copied to application database folder i.e. /data/data/<PackageName>/databases/. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929923/using-robolectric-with-sqliteassethelper/20932670#20932670

Comment: @ZohraKhan I don't have a database in my assets folder. The database is created in `onCreate` in my helper (that extends the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class). The problem is that Robolectric is using in memory database that is recreated every time `getWritableDatabase()` is called. I want to know how can I change this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the Robolectric source from github and made the changes explained in the answer to this question:

[Testing SQLite database in Robolectric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320820/testing-sqlite-database-in-robolectric?rq=1)

In the `ShadowSQLiteOpenHelper` class I made these changes:

- Defined this field:

  ```
  private static Context previousContext;
  ```
- In the constructor added this:

  ```
  if (previousContext == null) {
      previousContext = context;
  } else {
      if(previousContext == context) {
          return;
      } else {
          previousContext = context;
      }
  }
  ```
- Changed the `getDatabase()` method like this:

  ```
  private SQLiteDatabase getDatabase() {
      if (database == null) {
          database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("path", null, 0);
          realHelper.onCreate(database);
      }

      realHelper.onOpen(database);
      return database;
  }
  ```

And now everything works perfect.