# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError with Robolectric and Couchbase

Tags: unit-testing, android-sqlite, robolectric, android-testing, couchbase-lite

I am unable to get started with using Robolectric unit tests because of the following error it has with couchbase db.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.couchbase.lite.internal.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;ZZ)J
```

This error is thrown in my CouchbaseWrapper class at syntax,

```
    // Get existing db with that name
    // or create a new one if it doesn't exist.
    database = manager.getDatabase(dbname);
```

If I do `database = manager.getDatabase(dbname, true);`, then this step "passes" but other steps return NPE.

Here is my testcase:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class OnBoardingPageOneTest {

private OnboardingActivity onboardingActivity;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    onboardingActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(OnboardingActivity.class);
}

@Test
public void verifyElementsArePresent() {
    assertThat(onboardingActivity.findViewById(R.id.text_container), is(not(null)));
    assertThat(onboardingActivity.findViewById(R.id.intro_video_view), is(not(null)));
    assertThat(onboardingActivity.findViewById(R.id.play_button), is(not(null)));
    assertThat(onboardingActivity.findViewById(R.id.loading_progress), is(not(null)));
    }
}
```

Log

```
Library not found: /native/osx/x86_64/libsqlcipher.dylib
Library not found: /native/osx/x86_64/libsqlite3.dylib
Library not found: /native/osx/x86_64/libsqlcipher.dylib
Library not found: /native/osx/x86_64/libsqlite3.dylib

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.couchbase.lite.internal.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;ZZ)J

at com.couchbase.lite.internal.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
at com.couchbase.lite.internal.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:194)
at com.couchbase.lite.internal.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:178)
at com.couchbase.lite.internal.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:461)
at
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: SQLite support in Roboelectric may not be complete.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320820/testing-sqlite-database-in-robolectric/24578332#24578332

Comment: Are you on Windows?  based on [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mobile-couchbase/CFzgdYzQcHU/JsaFkpQMlRgJ) it looks like it may be an issue with couchbase lite not having windows resources by default.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: nope. Stopped using roboelectric overall.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is any way to run Couchbase Lite Android on Robolectric.

The problem is that in order to do, essentially, anything at all, Couchbase Lite has to load a native code engine, LiteCore.  LiteCore is written in C++ and is included in the Couchbase Lite Android aar.  The Android system unpacks the native library and puts it in a place from which it can be loaded, when the aar is installed.

Robolectric does not do this.  As a result the library cannot be loaded and any JNI calls will fail.